# unable to understand the destructor call sequence

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

```
class base{
    public:
        ~base(){
             cout<<"base class delete"<<endl;
        }   
};

class derived:public base{
    public:
        ~derived(){
            cout<<"derived class 1 delete"<<endl; 
        }
};

class derived2:public base,public derived{
    public:
        ~derived2(){
            cout<<"derived class 2 delete"<<endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    derived2 h; 
    return 0;
}
```

THE output produced is :

> derived class 2 delete
>   
>   derived class 1 delete
>   
>   base class delete
>   
>   base class delete

I know that destructors are called in reverse order of constructors, but I am unable to understand this output. Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: What exactly are you unable to understand? What do you see as strange in this output? What prompted the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** The destructors are called in reverse order from the most derived to the base.

**2)** The destruction of each non virtual base class is done in reverse order of their declaration

So in your case:

We start from a `derived2`, go the its last declared base (`derived`) to destroy it (destroying `derived` then `base`) and then come back to destroy the other base, which is `base`.

See also [this FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mi-vi-dtor-order.html) for more details and the general case with virtual bases.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors are called in reverse declaration-order. So once `derived2`'s destructor is called, then `derived`'s dtor is called, not `base`'s. Therefore, third output from base class is called by `derived` class. Once it is done, the one class left from `derived2` that was inherited is `base`, so fourth output is from `derived2` class.

to summarize:

1. first output is from derived2 class
2. second output is from derived class that was inherited by derived2 class
3. third output is from base class that was inherited by derived class
4. fourth output is from base class that was inherited by derived2 class

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this sequence of destruction:

```
derived 2 ==> derived 1 && base ==> base
```

Explanation:

- (a) Destructor of Derived 2 is called
- (b)`cout<<"derived class 2 delete"<<endl;` gets invoked from (a)
- (c) Destructor of Derived 1 is called.
- (d)`cout<<"derived class 1 delete"<<endl;` gets invoked from (c)
- (e) Destructor of base class gets  invoked from (c)
- (f) Destuctor of base class gets  from (a)

Answer (score 0):

Destructors execute in reverse order of constructors.

- Here, destruction started from 'Class derived 2' (so, its destructor is called first).
- Then the last inherited class is destroyed (i.e Class derived) by calling its destroctor: ~derived(){}. It has inherited a class i.e 'Class base', so its destroctor is called: ~base(){}.
- Finally, the first class inherited by 'Class derived 2' is destroyed (i.e Class base) by calling its destructor: ~base(){}

Comment: Does this answer include anything that wasn't said in the previous answers?